# NullPointerException when creating an SSL-Socket

Tags: android, ssl, nullpointerexception, httpclient

In my app I'm communicating with an webservice over SSL. Because I use a multipart entity which is not supported by android by default I included the following libraries:

- httpclient-4.1.1.jar
- httpcore-4.1.jar
- httpmime-4.1.1.jar

The server uses a certificate signed by an authority supported by android. This works on most devices though. Today one of my users (Android 2.2 Motorola Defy) sent me a log which contains the following:

```
W/System.err( 2328): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err( 2328): at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:83)
W/System.err( 2328): at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:375)
W/System.err( 2328): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:168)
W/System.err( 2328): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
W/System.err( 2328): at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
W/System.err( 2328): at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:352)
W/System.err( 2328): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
W/System.err( 2328): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
W/System.err( 2328): at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
W/System.err( 2328): at my.api.Client.sendRequest(Client.java)
...
```

I can't reproduce this on my devices and I have no clue why this happens. I looked into the source code of OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl and the only point where the NullPointerException can come from is because `sslParameters` is `null`. Do you have any idea what I can do in my code to work around this exception?

If you don't know how to solve the problem but have an idea what to ask the user who sent the log to me, please also place an answer.
I already asked him whether his browser shows error messages when he tries to access a website over https. I will append the reply here as soon as I received it.

Comment: Hi, I know this is really old, but did you manage to find a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

The traceback isn't an exact match but if your user is using a proxy server you might want to see if your version of HttpClient has the fix for this bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5255